# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in C:\xampp\htdocs\tempahperalatan\Page2.php on line 59

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm a student learning php and sql, I'm trying to insert a data from a checkbox with a quantity and I'm not sure with my coding, can anyone help me? There is an error in line 59.

This is my php coding:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tempahperalatan";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $catatan = $_POST['catatan'];

    $microphones=$row[microphones];

        if ($laptop=='1')
          { $vlaptop="ON";}
        else
          { $vlaptop="OFF";}

    $amplifiers=$row[amplifiers];
        if ($amplifiers=='1')
          {
            $vamplifiers="ON";
          }
          else
          {
          $vamplifiers="OFF";
          }

    $loudspeakers=$row[loudspeakers];
        if ($loudspeakers=='1')
          {
            $vloudspeakers="ON";
          }
          else
          {
          $vloudspeakers="OFF";
          }

    $mixers=$row[mixers];
        if ($mixers=='1')
          {
            $vmixers="ON";
          }
          else
          {
          $vmixers="OFF";
          }       

 $sql= "INSER INTO pasystems (catatan) INTO '$catatan'"


if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) { //this is line 59
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('failed!')</script>" . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}


}


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and this is my form:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">


        <div class="form-group row text-left">
          <label for="example-date-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Nama Peralatan: </label>
          <div class="col-10">

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-check text-left">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" name="Microphones" type="checkbox" 
                                <?      if ($row[microphones]==1)
                { ?> checked="checked" <?    }              
        ?> >
                                Microphones
                            </label>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="1" id="example-number-input">                              
                </div>                                  
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-check text-left">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" name="Amplifiers" type="checkbox" 
                                <?      if ($row[lamplifiers]==1)
                { ?> checked="checked" <?    }              
        ?> >
                                Amplifiers
                            </label>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="1" id="example-number-input">  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-check text-left">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" name="Loudspeakers" type="checkbox" 
                                <?      if ($row[loudspeakers]==1)
                { ?> checked="checked" <?    }              
        ?> >
                                Loudspeakers
                            </label>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="1" id="example-number-input">  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-check text-left">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" name="Mixers]" type="checkbox" 
                                <?      if ($row[mixers]==1)
                { ?> checked="checked" <?    }              
        ?> >
                                Mixers
                            </label>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="1" id="example-number-input">  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>                          

          </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group row text-left">
        <label for="exampleTextarea" class="col-2 col-form-label">Catatan: </label>
            <div class="col-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="catatan" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>                      
    <center><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button></center>   

</form>
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with my coding. Thank you in advance your help is much needed.

Comment: You need tell us what is the code at line 59 because we can't see any line numbers. Also if you're still learning stop using variables directly inside your `SQL` this opens the doors to a SQL injection attack switch to using prepared statements in `mysqli`. In your `SQL` try changing to this `INSER INTO pasystems (catatan) INTO '".$catatan."'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is that you have a wrong insert into syntax. You are missing the VALUES keyword and you misspelled INSERT and a missing semi colon 
The following below should fix it.

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO pasystems (catatan) VALUES('$catatan')";
```

Also the above code is not secure. You'll need to start using prepared statements as you are using an api that supports it

Answer (score 0):

Write insert in place of inser @58

Hope this will help you

Thanks